# Dependencies define the same class

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, ros

I am using a library cv_bridge (http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge) that defines a class Exception. This library depends on the library OpenCV which also defines a class Exception. Visual Studio 17 fails to build:

```
Error   LNK2005 "public: __cdecl std::exception::exception(class std::exception const &)" (??0exception@std@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z) already defined in cv_bridge.lib(cv_bridge.dll) my_project_name    C:\my_project_path\MSVCRTD.lib(throw_bad_alloc.obj) 

Error   LNK2005 "public: virtual char const * __cdecl std::exception::what(void)const " (?what@exception@std@@UEBAPEBDXZ) already defined in cv_bridge.lib(cv_bridge.dll) my_project_name   C:\my_project_path\MSVCRTD.lib(throw_bad_alloc.obj)
```

I need to link OpenCV in order to link cv_bridge, but I don't see how I can get around this multiple symbol problem.

Is there a way around this issue aside from re-building one of the libraries? Maybe some VS17 build settings that I can configure to handle this?

Some more context: The cv_bridge package is part of the larger ROS framework, and I've used it many times within the ROS framework on Ubuntu. Now I'm trying to build a DLL in Windows to invoke from some C# code. Is it possible the ROS framework build system can bypass this issue in an ad-hoc way, and I just need to reproduce that in Windows somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this issue is caused the the same defination of the class, since the two different exception classes are in different namespace.

You may try to change the configuration of the project, add the libraries to "Ignore Specific Library".

"Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Ignore Specific Library"

Add "msvcprtd.lib;MSVCRTD.lib" libraries.

Comment: You're correct - the problem was indeed MSVCRT.lib. Ignoring it did not work though. What worked was setting /FORCE:MULTIPLE in the linker command line arguments. That is suggested in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1169?view=vs-2019

I tried to play with the CRT settings in C/C++->Code Generation, but none of the settings worked.

Comment: @Sterling, if possible, could you please provide the project?